# How to sync passwords between Chrome and iCloud Keychain

Tags: icloud, safari, password, google-chrome, keychain

I'd like to use Chrome (currently Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)) and on my iPad I'd like to use Safari (obviously). Since 10.10 the sync between Chrome and MacOS Keychain stopped working for me.

Is there any trick to make this work again?

*1Password or other 3rd party password managers are currently no option for me, as I don't trust their security. (see [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/28/flaws_in_password_management_apps/) or [here](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/03/potent-lastpass-exploit-underscores-the-dark-side-of-password-managers/))*

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I've used 1Password for a number of years and have been very happy with it across all my devices. It is constantly updated, so I'm sure they're on top of patching vulnerabilities. Evenso, I don't use it with iCloud (or any cloud service) and personally don't use the various web browser extensions. Having worked in the IT Security field, I know we can only ever _manage_ the risk, not eliminate it. That's why I choose not to use anything to store passwords etc in the cloud (not even Keychain), but I _may_ be overly cautious in that choice.

Comment: @Monomeeth how do you sync passwords between devices? Manually?

Comment: After the initial setup (when a lot of entries are made), adding new entries doesn't happen often. And since it's not common, syncing manually is no big deal (and it's very quick). For example, if I'm away from home and I've added a new password (or whatever) into the 1Password app on my iPhone, all I need to do when at home is launch the 1Password app on the Mac select the necessary option and the data is synced between both devices. It's all over in less than a minute, and data goes both ways (e.g. if my wife added a new password at home, it's now also on my iPhone). Works for me.

Comment: While it is true that Chrome no longer works with iCloud Keychain out of the box, perhaps you might want to use this [Chrome extension that connects to iCloud Keychain](https://winchpass.com) that I've made. I've made it to use on my old Windows PC but it works on any Chrome browser.

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.4 release notes say: "Safari: Option to import Chrome passwords into your iCloud Keychain for easy AutoFill of your passwords in Safari and across all your devices" - maybe that helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308098/sync-chrome-passwords-with-apple-icloud-keychain/327262#327262):

> You can no longer share Google Chrome passwords with iCloud Keychain.
>   Google Chrome 45 was the last one that could do it. Since then its
>   been removed as an option.
>
> Perhaps reaching out to Google Support and giving them something to
>   pass on to the devs for Chrome for Mac could inspire something.
>
> Until they replace it, I recommend using a 3rd Party option since they
>   work with nearly every platform and device type. Such as LastPass,
>   Dashlane, Roboform, Keepass, 1Password, Privacy, GNOME keyring, etc.
>
> They may work with Keychain and gather passwords saved in Chrome.
>   Thats the only auto-sync solution that is available.

Comment: You should link to the SO answer that you copied, rather then just copy/pasting it.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327262

Comment: The other SO question (thank you for the link @Tom) also has an [answer](/a/342140/115893) suggesting the python script https://github.com/nntarasov/csv2keychain .

Answer (score 3):

open Safari ,click menu File->Import From->Google Chrome, select password and click import

Comment: This is the right answer. Safari now also has an "export" passwords option too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not believe that there is an easy way to do this.  I think your only options are to either:
1) Use a third-party manager after looking up reviews for it;
or
2) Whenever you make a new password, you input it into both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that you can't use the keychain in Chrome, I can suggest a solution that I've made.

The explanation involves some web dev, so skip to the end if this is too boring.
The extension has two parts:

- The extension itself.
- A static website at https://winchpass.com that your iDevice opens.

The extension generates a QR code and you scan it with your regular iPhone camera.
It opens the static website (hosted at [GH pages](https://github.com/igor-makarov/winchpass-server)) with the necessary parameters in the query string.
Because the website is static, it receives no data.
The QR code URL also contains a one-time pad encryption key. This key is passed through the URL hash.

You use the Keychain on your iPhone to enter the password, which is encrypted using the key and sent to the extension using WebSockets. The key is unusable after that. The built-in Safari functionality allows you to save the password for later reuse.

You can get it here: [WinchPass - iCloud Keychain for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kalncabcefgchiphkgoiiglapkoopeal)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Apple Keychain passwords in Chrome on iOS (you cannot update them or create new ones from Chrome).