# Sync Chrome passwords with Apple iCloud Keychain

Tags: icloud, password, google-chrome, keychain

Is there a tool or a process where I can [export](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309160/export-google-chrome-password)/sync my Google Chrome saved passwords into iCloud Keychain?

Comment: I actually wrote a program to decrypt Chrome passwords in hopes of doing exactly this (copying to iCloud Keychain). Unfortunately, it would seem that Safari is granted a special entitlement which allows it to read and write from iCloud Keychain. I did consider writing a library to inject into Safari that would basically strap my current functionality and hijack Safari's abilities, but I got a bit tired of the project. I guess if there was demand for it, I could take another look.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just did that using Safari 13.1.1 (on Catalina 10.15.5).

1. Open Chrome (if not already running) to refresh its cache
2. Quit Chrome completely (`⌘`-`Q`)
3. Open Safari (if not already running)
4. Click **File** > **Import From** > **Google Chrome...**, select **Password** (and, optionally, **Bookmarks** and/or **History**), click **Import**
5. Enter login password & click **Allow** twice (once to use "Chrome Safe Storage" information, and once to access it)
6. Voilà, all your preciously maintained Chrome passwords are available in Keychain across all your devices & apps!

This is a one-time operation and has to be repeated periodically; it also does not provide synchronization the other way...

Comment: Amazing, this is perfect!

Comment: If anyone knows how to do it in the other direction and maintain the sync automatically, let me know...

Comment: I've been on this question before, but this time it has a good answer. Thank you

Answer (score 16):

I've created small tool to deliver your credentials from Chrome into macOS keychain. Here is a page on github https://github.com/nntarasov/csv2keychain

The program interacts with macOS command-line utility called security with option add-internet-password. First of all you have to manually export credetials from chrome into .csv file. There is such feature in Chrome. So, the idea is very simple - the list of credentials from file is being added into system keychain via security

Comment: You are a hero!

Comment: here are some valid tutorials on how to export passwords from chrome https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/how-to-export-your-passwords-and-login-data-from-google-chrome/

Answer (score 9):

You can no longer share Google Chrome passwords with iCloud Keychain. Google Chrome 45 was the last one that could do it. Since then its been removed as an option.

Perhaps reaching out to Google Support and giving them something to pass on to the devs for Chrome for Mac could inspire something.

Until they replace it, I recommend using a 3rd Party option since they work with nearly every platform and device type. Such as LastPass, Dashlane, Roboform, Keepass, 1Password, Privacy, GNOME keyring, etc.

They may work with Keychain and gather passwords saved in Chrome. Thats the only auto-sync solution that is available.

Comment: FYI Dont use lastpass, they have had multiple breaches including having all customer data (encrypted and unencrypted) stolen.  https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/lastpass-breach-what-subscribers-need-to-know-and-do/