# Export Google Chrome Password

Tags: password, google-chrome

I am hoping that someone knows how to do this. I've been searching online for days now and I have found no solution that works. So, I am looking for a way to export the passwords saved on Chrome as a CSV file to import it into my password manager (Enpass).

My System:
`macOS: 10.13.2
Chrome: 63.0.3239.84`

Here is what I have tried to far:

- In Chrome, I went to: `chrome://flags/#password-import-export`
- Then I enabled "Password import and export" and have relaunched Chrome
- Then I went to: Settings > Advanced > Manage passwords
- I see the export button, when I click on it, it asks me to where I want to save it, I selected "Desktop" and clicked Save.
- Now that open the file (a CSV) and open it, I only see the headers and no data.

The CSV looks something like this:

`name   url username    password`