# Sharing Keychain in Chrome

Tags: safari, password, google-chrome, keychain

Is it possible to configure Keychain to share passwords in Chrome on OS X Catalina?
The problem I face is that some websites function better in Chrome than Safari and I would like to be able to switch between the two browsers and use auto-logins in each. Currently I can do this in Safari if use Keychain and Password autocomplete. I would like to be able to do same or similar in Chrome.

Comment: Will this help you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308098/sync-chrome-passwords-with-apple-icloud-keychain

Comment: thanks, it's the other way around I'm looking for...